# How to pull images via Json? I want to display images for each of the corresponding audio tracks. I'm using playlist support

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I want to display a music cover-album for each of the tracks when is playing!

This audio player features playlist support via JSON data and step navigation. The version you're seeing now is a fresh new take on this project... by modernizing the style and offloading all browser detection crap to a wonderful audio player plugin called Plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

I recreate the position of the thumbnails in my CSS, but UNFORTUNATELY, I still did not figure out what I have to do in my Js code to make this work it out!

Precious help to improve my code?

HAVE A LOOK TO MY FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/1oL6w5jm/10/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    'use strict'
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        // initialize plyr
        var player = new Plyr('#audio1', {
            controls: [
                'restart',
                'play',
                'progress',
                'current-time',
                'duration',
                'mute',
                'volume',
                'download'
            ]
        });
        // initialize playlist and controls
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 3,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "5:01",
                "file": "BS_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 4,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "8:31",
                "file": "BSFM_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 5,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "BSFM_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 6,
                "name": "All This Is - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "AC_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 7,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 1) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:44",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 8,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 2) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:26",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 9,
                "name": "Magus - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "AC_M"
            }, {
                "track": 10,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address (fucked up) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:25",
                "file": "AC_TSOWAfucked_up"
            }, {
                "track": 11,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "5:53",
                "file": "PNY04-05_M"
            }, {
                "track": 12,
                "name": "On The Waterfront - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "4:40",
                "file": "PNY04-05_OTW"
            }, {
                "track": 13,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "13:15",
                "file": "PNY04-05_T"
            }, {
                "track": 14,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "8:12",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 15,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "7:02",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 16,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:43",
                "file": "PVD_M"
            }, {
                "track": 17,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "10:45",
                "file": "PVD_T"
            }, {
                "track": 18,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:36",
                "file": "PVD_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 19,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 20,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_M"
            }, {
                "track": 21,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "13:07",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_BTPE"
            }, {
                "track": 22,
                "name": "Innocence - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:16",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_I"
            }, {
                "track": 23,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 24,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "4:51",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 25,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "8:43",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 26,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "3:00",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 27,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "6:09",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 28,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 29,
                "name": "Trance - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "12:32",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_T"
            }, {
                "track": 30,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "8:56",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 31,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "4:55",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 32,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "5:45",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 33,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "14:05",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 34,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "13:25",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 35,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:37",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 36,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:36",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_2"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li> \
                    <div class="plItem"> \
                        <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span> \
                        <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                        <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </li>');
            }),
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).on('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).on('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
                updateDownload(id, audio.src);
            },
            updateDownload = function (id, source) {
                player.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
                    $('a[data-plyr="download"]').attr('href', source);
                });
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
    } else {
        // no audio support
        $('.column').addClass('hidden');
        var noSupport = $('#audio1').text();
        $('.container').append('<p class="no-support">' + noSupport + '</p>');
    }
});
```

```
/* Album thumbnail should display here when track is playing
================================================== */
.flex-container {
    width:70vh;
    //pointer-events:none;
  display:block;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:999999999999;
    position:fixed;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    //background:black;
}

.track-thumbnails img {
  //transform: rotate(5deg);
  width: 40vh;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);

}

/* Font Family
================================================== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700');


/* Global Styles
================================================== */

html,body {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
background-color:#0665a2;
color:#fff;
font-size:1rem;
font-family:"Oxygen", HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
letter-spacing:.025rem;
line-height:1.618;
padding:1rem 0;
}

*,::before,::after {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}


/* Setup
================================================== */

.container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; width:100%; }
.column { width:inherit; }


/* Typography / Links
================================================== */

p { color:#fff; display:block; font-size:.9rem; font-weight:400; margin:0 0 2px; }

a,a:visited { color:#8cc3e6; outline:0; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover,a:focus { color:#bbdef5; }
p a,p a:visited { line-height:inherit; }


/* Misc.
================================================== */

.add-bottom { margin-bottom:2rem !important; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.center { text-align:center; }
.hidden { display:none; }

.no-support {
margin:2rem auto;
text-align:center;
width:90%;
}


/* Audio Player Styles
================================================== */

audio {
display:none;
}

#audiowrap,
#plwrap {
margin:0 auto;
}

#tracks {
font-size:0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#nowPlay {
display:block;
font-size:0;
}

#nowPlay span {
display:inline-block;
font-size:1.05rem;
vertical-align:top;
}

#nowPlay span#npAction {
padding:21px;
width:30%;
}

#nowPlay span#npTitle {
padding:21px;
text-align:right;
width:70%;
}

#plList li {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:21px 0;
}

#plList li:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plItem {
position:relative;
}

.plTitle {
left:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:65px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
top:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.plNum {
padding-left:21px;
width:25px;
}

.plLength {
padding-left:21px;
position:absolute;
right:21px;
top:0;
}

.plSel,
.plSel:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
cursor:default !important;
}

#tracks a {
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:2.3rem;
height:35px;
line-height:.175;
margin:0 5px 30px;
padding:10px 15px;
text-decoration:none;
transition:background .3s ease;
}

#tracks a:last-child {
margin-left:0;
}

#tracks a:hover,
#tracks a:active {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
}

#tracks a::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
padding:0;
}


/* Plyr Overrides
================================================== */

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls {
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 20px 20px 13px;
width:100%;
}

a.plyr__controls__item.plyr__control:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button.tab-focus:focus,
.plyr__play-large {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr__progress--played,
.plyr__volume--display {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer,
.plyr--audio .plyr__volume--display {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


/* Media Queries
================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #nowPlay span#npAction { display:none; }
    #nowPlay span#npTitle { display:block; text-align:center; width:100%; }
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css">





<div class="container">
    <div class="column add-bottom">
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="nowPlay">
                <span id="npAction">Paused...</span><span id="npTitle"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="audiowrap">
                <div id="audio0">
                    <audio id="audio1" preload controls>Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio! </audio>
                </div>
                <div id="tracks">




<div class="flex-container"><div class="track-thumbnails">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_171d59a550b%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_171d59a550b%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.7109375%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
</div></div>






                    <a id="btnPrev">&vltri;</a><a id="btnNext">&vrtri;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="plwrap">
                <ul id="plList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column add-bottom center">
        <p>Music by <a href="http://www.mythium.net/">Mythium</a></p>
        <p>Download: <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_vbr_mp3.zip">zip</a> / <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_archive.torrent">torrent</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you pulling the images? The json doesn't seem to contain any image references.

Comment: Exactly, @DanielBlack I'm trying to figure out how to pull the images via Json...something like:   "track", "name", "duration", "file",  "images?"

Comment: @DanielBlack  any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not familiar with site your are pulling from to know where they store their album thumbnails. I took a look at the link from the json and saw they have track audio images. If you add this line `$(".track-thumbnails img").attr('src', mediaPath + tracks[id].file + '.png')` to the `loadTrack` function it loads them. If you find other images you can use something similar to pull them instead.

Comment: @DanielBlack Many thanks! Would you not mind to edit and show me an example with my fiddle code? https://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/1oL6w5jm/10/ .  Any blank images from google would work in combination for any of the track in the playlist. I'm not so expert in Js :(

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/fj58pe7z/. Your styling for the images still need some work as they block the buttons if you make them bigger. I've only added the image references to the first three JSON blocks. This should be enough for you to figure it out from here.

Comment: @DanielBlack  exactly what I was asking for. Thanks a million Daniel